# unable to write symref for HEAD: Permission denied unable to update HEAD

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

Git checkout to new branch gives below error

> unable to write symref for HEAD: Permission denied unable to update
>   HEAD

But it works if I delete the repo and create a new one. The moment I restart my laptop I guess it stops working.

The problem is in Windows 10.

Comment: do you have proper permission after restart ?

Comment: Yes there was some issue with the permission. Since it was office laptop so have raised the issue with the IT department.

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me when I had git and 2 Visual studio instances open with the same solution. Git checkout gave the same error and showed some changes as staged for commit when they shouldn't have been. I've reverted those changes, closed one of the Visual Studios and tried checkout again, it worked nicely.

Comment: For me problem was super random. I've found the culprit. First I downloaded Sysinternals ProcessExplorer, ran it as admin and used Find->Find Handle or DLL. Then I typed git to search for processes with files open in git directory. System (!!!) had  `../.git/modules/.../HEAD` open. Besides this there were many files opened in some Ubuntu folder. I tried to close all Window Subsystem For Linux windows, didn't help.
The solution was to run command prompt as admin and write
```
wsl --list --running
wsl --terminate Ubuntu-22.04
```
Problem was WSL and bash-powerline script.

Comment: Yeah I restarted my PC and it worked fine. Quite odd. ( I am using Windows)

Comment: committing and reloading VS-Code did it for me. No idea what caused that.

Comment: In my case "Developer: Reload Window" did not help but closing all VS Code instances and reopening them did.